# VB.Net Regular Expressions - Extracting Wildcard Value

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, wildcard, extract

I need help extracting the value of a wildcard from a Regular Expressions match. For example:

**Regex:** "I like *"

**Input:** "I like chocolate"

I would like to be able to extract the string "chocolate" from the Regex match (or whatever else is there). If possible, I also want to be able to retrieve several wildcard values from a single wildcard match. For example:

**Regex:** "I play the * and  the *"

**Input:** "I play the guitar and the bass"

I want to be able to extract both "guitar" and "bass". Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general regex utilize the concepts of groups. Groups are indicated by parenthesis.

So **I like**  
Would be I like (.) . = All character * meaning as many or none of the preceding character

```
Sub Main()
    Dim s As String = "I Like hats"
    Dim rxstr As String = "I Like(.*)"
    Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(s, rxstr)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(1))

End Sub
```

The above code will work for and string that has I Like and will print out all characters after including the ' ' as . matches even white space.

Your second case is more interesting because the first rx will match the entire end of the string you need something more restrictive.

I Like (\w+) and (\w+) : this will match `I Like then a space` and one or more word characters and then an `and` a space and `one or more word characters`

```
Sub Main()

    Dim s2 As String = "I Like hats and dogs"
    Dim rxstr2 As String = "I Like (\w+) and (\w+)"
    Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(s2, rxstr2)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", m.Groups(1), m.Groups(2))
End Sub
```

For a more complete treatment of [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) take a look at this site which has a great tutorial.

Comment: Right on. Only thing to take care is the greedyness of wild cards.

Comment: Thanks, by the way is there a way to return the wildcard value the way it was originally written if I have the IgnoreCase Regex Option turned on? Example: "I like GeRmAnY" returns "GeRmAnY"

Answer (score 0):

Here is my RegexExtract Function in VBA. It will return just the sub match you specify (only the stuff in parenthesis). So in your case, you'd write:

```
 =RegexExtract(A1, "I like (.*)")
```

Here is the code.

```
Function RegexExtract(ByVal text As String, _
                      ByVal extract_what As String) As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim allMatches As Object
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = extract_what
RE.Global = True
Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)
RegexExtract = allMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Here is a version that will allow you to use multiple groups to extract multiple parts at once:

```
Function RegexExtract(ByVal text As String, _
                      ByVal extract_what As String) As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim allMatches As Object
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
Dim i As Long
Dim result As String

RE.Pattern = extract_what
RE.Global = True
Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)

For i = 0 To allMatches.Item(0).submatches.count - 1
    result = result & allMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(i)
Next

RegexExtract = result
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```